# Bluemix SSO - How to logout?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I've got a Java Bluemix application configured with the SSO Service connected with a SAML 2.0 and a Cloud Directory. I'm having problems to accomplish a successful logout.
Do you know what's the correct procedure to accomplish a SSO logout from a link in my application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could simply destroy the session and make expire all the cookie on your application domain

Comment: The problem is that i need to force the expiration of ibmcloud.com's cookies in order to be able to select a new identity, and i can not do it from my application.